# make x axis and ticks disappear in d3

Tags: d3.js, visualization

I'd like to make only the x-axis labels disappear. Currently, I have the following code, but it makes the entire x-axis disappear, and I'd like to keep the horizontal line.

Is there a way to just target the ticks and the text alone?

```
// Make x-axis
let xAxis = d3.axisBottom(scaleX);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .attr("opacity", 0.7)
  .call(xAxis);

// Target x-axis; but this targets the entire axis
let setXAxisOpacity = (opacity, duration=120) => {
    d3.select(".axis")
     .transition()
     .duration(duration)
     .ease(d3.easeLinear)
     .style("opacity", opacity)
}
```

Comment: Might be easiest just to hide them with css.

Answer (score 1):

you need to target the `text` and `line` parts of the axis

```
d3.select('.axis').selectAll('text')
     .transition()
     .duration(duration)
     .ease(d3.easeLinear)
     .style("opacity", opacity);
d3.select('.axis').selectAll('line')
     .transition()
     .duration(duration)
     .ease(d3.easeLinear)
     .style("opacity", opacity);
```

Comment: Why do you need to target the path?

Comment: I though you wanted to **only** keep the labels. Don't do the `path` if you want the horizontal line, but it still has the end-ticks

Comment: I just asked out of curiosity, I'm not OP ;)